# Rails params issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a basic survey app. I'm attempting to create a choice with whatever answer the user creates, but for some reason my question isn't getting set in my choice controller.

Here's my routes:

```
  resources :questions do
    resources :choices, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

My view:

```
<h3>Questions:</h3>
<ul><% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
    <li><p><%= question.title %></p></li>
    <% choice = question.choices.build %>
    <% if question.single_response == true %>
    <%= form_for [question, choice] do |f| %>

            <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
            <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id %> <%= answer.title %><br>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :survey_id, value: @survey.id %>
            <%= f.submit %>
```

My set_question method in my choice controller:

```
def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    end
```

And then my create method:

```
 def create
    @choice = @question.choices.build(choice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @choice.save
        format.html { redirect_to surveys_path, notice: 'Choice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @choice }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @choice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Which is netting a nil class error.

```
undefined method `choices' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: /Users/thomashammond89/SurveyMe
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/choices_controller.rb:27:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XjNNShH6jvTAcz1NQqSBU+a+2exP2STPFnja+yfbinY=",
 "choice"=>{"answer_id"=>"19",
 "survey_id"=>"1",
 "question_id"=>"13"},
 "commit"=>"Create Choice",
 "question_id"=>"13"}
```

Which looks to me that the question_id is there in the params. Any idea why it's not getting set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't defining the instance variable `@question` in your create action. Try:

```
@question = Question.find(params[:choice][:question_id])
```

Comment: That did the trick. Do you know why my before_action didn't work? Maybe I'm just not understanding something, but that's how I've always set the instance variable before.

Comment: Look at the structure of the params hash. You were calling `Question.find(params[:question_id])` while the key `:question_id` is inside of `params[:choice][:question_id]` .